# Need Excel VBA Code to paste into next blank cell in Column A

Tags: vba, excel

The code that I have currently pastes the data in Column A of worksheet "Projects" into the next blank row on worksheet "Assignment".  I would like it to paste into the first blank cell on worksheet "Assignment" instead.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPasteX()
    'Declare variables
    Dim projName As String
    Dim projCount As Integer, lRow As Integer, lRow2 As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

    'Find last row
    lRow = Sheets("Projects").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Begin loop - CHANGE BELOW FROM 2 TO 1 IF SPREADSHEET DOES NOT INCLUDE HEADDERS
    For i = 2 To lRow

        'Set project names and the project count
        projName = Sheets("Projects").Range("A" & i)
        projCount = Sheets("Projects").Range("B" & i)

        'Second loop for pasting in project
        For j = 1 To projCount

            'Find last row on sheet 2
            lRow2 = Sheets("Assignment").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


            'Paste in the project name on sheet2
            Sheets("Assignment").Range("A" & lRow2 + 1).Value = projName

        'Loop to continue copying based on the project count
        Next j

    'Loop to next project
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I amended the lRow2 definition and refactored the whole code to take advantage of `With ... End With` sintax and reference proper sheet

```
Sub CopyPasteX()
    'Declare variables

    Dim lRow2 As Integer, j As Long

    Dim cell As Range
    With Sheets("Projects") 'reference wanted sheet
        'loop through referenced sheet column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
        'Begin loop - CHANGE BELOW FROM "A2" TO "A1" IF SPREADSHEET DOES NOT INCLUDE HEADDERS
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

            'Second loop for pasting in project, taking current cell adjacent one as the ending value
            For j = 1 To cell.Offset(, 1)

                'Find firts empty cell on sheet Assignment
                With Sheets("Assignment")
                    Select Case True
                        Case IsEmpty(.Range("A1"))
                            lRow2 = 0
                        Case WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))) = 1
                            lRow2 = 1
                        Case Else
                            lRow2 = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
                    End Select
                    .Range("A" & lRow2 + 1).Value = cell.Value 'Paste current cell value (i.e. project name) in referenced sheet column A at row lRow
                End With

            'Loop to continue copying based on the project count
            Next

        'Loop to next project
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This was initially working, but now I'm getting Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch error on this line 

    For j = 1 To cell.Offset(, 1)

Comment: seems like some value in column B is not an integer one, or maybe even an "error" value. query Immediate Window with `?cell.Offset(,1)`

Comment: @KevinLeer, can you check what in my last comment?

Comment: @KevinLeer. please consider that your question was _" I would like it to paste into the first blank cell on worksheet "Assignment" instead"_ and as per this site rules you should accept the answer that solves this very issue and start a new question for any different one. That being said, I'd be glad to help you in further needs, as my last comment should prove you. Thank you

Comment: I updated to show that your code is the answer.  I made some adjustments to my workbook that likely broke the code, but I had an earlier revision that worked.  I'm retracing my steps to find the issue.  I apologize if I broke any site rules and I appreciate all of your help more than you know.

Comment: @KevinLeer, what happened?

Comment: No idea what was causing an issue, but I've used it extensively after reverting to a previous version of the workbook and haven't had any issues.  Thanks again.

Comment: And so which solution did you adopt?

Comment: I ended up using your solution for the workbook.  I did figure out that the issue occurred when putting in an if statement on one of the referenced cells when copied.

Comment: Well, then please consider marking my answer as the solutionz. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
            'Find last row on sheet 2
           lRow2 = Sheets("Assignment").[A1].End(xlDown).Row
```

I found that this works exactly how I need it to.

Edit: This does not work as noted in the reply.

Comment: that wouldn't work should whole column or first row be empty . see  my edited code

Answer (score 0):

No need for inner loop. Try this code

```
Sub CopyPasteX()
Dim projName    As String
Dim projCount   As Integer
Dim lRow        As Integer
Dim lRow2       As Integer
Dim i           As Integer

lRow = Sheets("Projects").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow
    projName = Sheets("Projects").Range("A" & i)
    projCount = Sheets("Projects").Range("B" & i)

    lRow2 = Sheets("Assignment").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lRow2 = IIf(lRow2 = 1, 1, lRow2 + 1)

    Sheets("Assignment").Range("A" & lRow2).Resize(projCount).Value = projName
Next i
End Sub
```

Another code (using arrays)

```
Sub Test()
Dim arr         As Variant
Dim temp()      As String
Dim i           As Long
Dim j           As Long
Dim k           As Long

arr = Sheets("Projects").Range("A2:B" & Sheets("Projects").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value

j = 1: k = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    k = k + arr(i, 2)
    ReDim Preserve temp(1 To k)
    For j = j To k
        temp(j) = arr(i, 1)
    Next j
    j = k
Next i

With Sheets("Assignment").Range("A1")
    .Resize(k - 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(temp)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch error on this line:  

projCount = Sheets("Projects").Range("B" & i)

I did change column B to a formula referenced from another cell, but even when removing the formula and inputting a number it gives the error message.

Comment: What the value of the variable i when the error occurs .. ? the code works fine for me

Comment: What's the value of "projCount" variable at row four?

Comment: Your code worked.  I can't figure out how I broke it, but I reverted back to a previous version and it worked out fine.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I have added another code using arrays